# Command for hidden folders for git in windows

Tags: windows, command-line

What are the commands for showing the hidden folders in Git repository in windows?

For example - command in mac is `ls -la` or `ls -a`.

I am new to git.

Comment: Did you see them when you tried the commands out? What about running `man ls` then you can read what those options do

Comment: @evolutionxbox Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'la'. This is the error I got.

Comment: `-la` a shorthand for two options. `-l` and `-a`. Maybe your terminal doesn’t support the shorthand?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way : start  a terminal using `git-bash`, or from WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

You will have a `bash` shell with access to the standard linux utilies, and `ls -la` should work from such terminals.

---

If you started a Powershell terminal, try `ls -Hidden`.

`ls` is actually an *alias* to the powershell command : `Get-ChildItem`.

The Powershell team mapped a number of usual linux command names to Powershell built-ins (e.g : `cd` -> `Set-Location`, `uniq` -> `Get-Unique`, `pushd` -> `Push-Location`, ... ), but didn't map the options, so the options expected by `ls` in a Powershell terminal *aren't* `-a` ... but rather  the options to `Get-ChildItem`.

One way to figure out what's expected from a "linux" command name you know is to type : `get-help <command name>` you will see the actual powershell command name, and the options it expects, for example :

```
$ get-help ls

NAME
    Get-ChildItem

SUMMARY
    Gets the items and child items in one or more specified locations.


SYNTAX
    Get-ChildItem [[-Filter] <System.String>] [-Attributes {Archive | Compressed | Device | Directory | Encrypted |
    Hidden | IntegrityStream | Normal | NoScrubData | NotContentIndexed | Offline | ReadOnly | ReparsePoint |
    SparseFile | System | Temporary}] [-Depth <System.UInt32>] [-Directory] [-Exclude <System.String[]>] [-File]
    [-Force] [-Hidden] [-Include <System.String[]>] -LiteralPath <System.String[]> [-Name] [-ReadOnly] [-Recurse]
    [-System] [-UseTransaction] [<CommonParameters>]

    Get-ChildItem [[-Path] <System.String[]>] [[-Filter] <System.String>] [-Attributes {Archive | Compressed | Device
    | Directory | Encrypted | Hidden | IntegrityStream | Normal | NoScrubData | NotContentIndexed | Offline | ReadOnly
    | ReparsePoint | SparseFile | System | Temporary}] [-Depth <System.UInt32>] [-Directory] [-Exclude
    <System.String[]>] [-File] [-Force] [-Hidden] [-Include <System.String[]>] [-Name] [-ReadOnly] [-Recurse]
    [-System] [-UseTransaction] [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    The `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet gets the items in one or more specified locations. [...]
```

Comment: Is this a programming question then?

Comment: @evolutionbox : more of a shell / command line question IMHO

Answer (score 1):

If the OP is asking to simply see the hidden `.git` folder in a regular Windows Command terminal (cmd.exe), then the easiest is to use the `dir` command with the `/a` attribute. This is the simplest native equivalent to `ls -a`.

```
C:\Users\--redacted-->dir /a
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is --redacted--

 Directory of C:\Users\--redacted--

2022-10-29  10:31 PM    <DIR>          .
2022-10-29  10:31 PM    <DIR>          ..
2022-10-29  10:31 PM    <DIR>          .git
2022-10-29  10:31 PM               489 .gitignore
...
```

If you do not use the `/a`, you don't see the .git folder:

```
C:\Users\--redacted-->dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is --redacted--

 Directory of C:\Users\--redacted--

2022-10-29  10:31 PM    <DIR>          .
2022-10-29  10:31 PM    <DIR>          ..
2022-10-29  10:31 PM               489 .gitignore
...
```

This is because the `.git` folder has the Hidden Windows file attribute set, as can be seen with the `attrib` command:

```
C:\Users\--redacted-->attrib .git
    H                C:\Users\--redacted--\.git
```

Enter `dir /?` for all the flags that can be used with `dir`.

Answer (score 0):

First u have to find the path mostly it is in desktop
C:\Users\my pc\Desktop\ .git
if you find the folder
simply enter the path into the File explorer then hit enter
then the files is in that folder only simply copy and paste it wherever you want

Comment: You wrote in your answer: _First u have to find the path_ I believe that is the actual question, i.e. **how** to find the path.

Comment: C:\Users\my pc\Desktop\ .git most of the time this is the path if u create a git init

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).